# Checking string like boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript

I have below set of code -

```
if(!obj.Substance){
 ...Some Code...
}
```

In this condition Substance variable is of string type.

I want to check on which condition code will enter within if block?
I tried setting Substance value as `undefined` , `blank = empty string` also tried to put some value. But code did not entered in if block.

Comment: Can you give an actual [mre]? It's not clear what `blank` is but both `undefined` and an empty string `''` are false-y.

Comment: @jonrsharpe setting empty or undefined I tried , but its not entering within if block

Comment: what is the substance value. I mean console log value

Comment: No, an _actual MRE_. Also what does this have to do with [tag:jquery] or [tag:reactjs]?

Comment: Code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbw6f4dr/  must be what you're passing in, which you didn't provide.  See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will only enter the if block if the obj.Substance variable is falsey.

The following values are [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy):

- false
- 0
- "" (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN

So, if obj.Substance is any of those values, the code will enter the if block.